# How to Initialize Codable ObservedObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, codable, observedobject

In SwiftUI, I'm trying to create a class that conforms `Codable` (so I can save it in `@AppStorage`), and has `@Published` properties so it can be passed as an `EnvironmentObject`.

[This](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/adding-codable-conformance-for-published-properties) tutorial gave me the following example:

```
class User: ObservableObject, Codable {
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
    }
    
    @Published var name = "Bob Smith"
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how I would go about passing a `String` into the class initializer. (i.e. `var user = User("Bob Smith"`)

Unless I'm mistaken, `required` means that all instances & subclasses must use that initializer. Given that `name` is already being assigned in the existing initializer, how would I go about passing a custom name into the initializer of this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `required` means that all subclasses must implement the init and in this case it's a requirement because of the conformance to `Codable`.

But this doesn't mean you can't add other initialisers so that you can create instances of your class from other type of data than JSON

So simply add wathever init you need

```
init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}

let user = User(name: "Joe")
```

And for a sub class you must add an `init(from:)` and you might add another custom init if you want to, here is an example

```
class SuperUser: User {
    var likesBananas: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case likesBananas
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        likesBananas = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .likesBananas)

        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    init(name: String, likesBananas: Bool) {
        self.likesBananas = likesBananas
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {...}
}
```

Comment: Got it, thank you! is there any way to pass custom values into a subclass? or not, since they have to use the required initializer?

Comment: You create another custom init then with whatever values you need besides the required `init(from:)`

Comment: Oh, so `required` doesn't mean that's the ONLY initializer the subclass can have, but rather that is has to be ONE of the subclass' initializers?

Comment: Exactly, it's the same as for the super class example

Comment: I added an example